# How to group similar phrases in column of SQL table?

Tags: php, sql, grouping

In the table there are thousands of popular music bands and these names can be written in different ways. For example:

- "Red Hot Chili Peppers in Hungary"
- "Concert Red Hot Chili Peppers"
- "Red Hot Chili Peppers"
- "Red Hot (Live in CA)"

In each row there is a field *group_id*. And this field must be the same for all similar artists. For example, the smallest ID in the group:

```
id   | name                                 |  group_id
-------------------------------------------------------
1137 | "Red Hot Chili Peppers in Hungary"   | 1137
1138 | "Concert Red Hot Chili Peppers"      | 1137
1139 | "Red Hot Chili Peppers"              | 1137
1140 | "Red Hot (Live in CA)"               | 1137
```

Now the *group_id* in all rows empty. How correctly to combine similar names and assign them *group_id*?

Comment: Can you offer a more precise definition for "similar" in the context of your question?

Comment: Google:  "Levenshtein distance".  There is probably an implementation for your database.

Comment: I helped a little bit of formatting, but removing the lot of nbsp;-s remains for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for fun, here's some sample Postgres code (which RDBMS are you using?) for a levenstein as gordon mentioned, but the problem isn't so simple.

```
create extension fuzzystrmatch 

create table t (id serial, txt text)
insert into t(txt) values('Red Hot Chili Peppers in Hungary');
insert into t(txt) values('Concert Red Hot Chili Peppers');
insert into t(txt) values('Red Hot Chili Peppers');
insert into t(txt) values('Red Hot (Live in CA)');

select a.txt a, b.txt b,  levenshtein(a.txt, b.txt)  from t as a inner join t as b on a.id < b.id
```

which returns

```
"Red Hot Chili Peppers in Hungary";"Concert Red Hot Chili Peppers";19
"Red Hot Chili Peppers in Hungary";"Red Hot Chili Peppers";11
"Red Hot Chili Peppers in Hungary";"Red Hot (Live in CA)";18
"Concert Red Hot Chili Peppers";"Red Hot Chili Peppers";8
"Concert Red Hot Chili Peppers";"Red Hot (Live in CA)";19
"Red Hot Chili Peppers";"Red Hot (Live in CA)";11
```

however, now you have to do something with these distances (the number in the last col). The larger the number the greater the distance, the greater the distance the less similar. So, you can easily create a lookup table that binds each string to a score, but you'll end up with items falling in many groups, thus not really achieving a grouping.

Depending on how much data you have, you could pull it out, cluster it with something like KMeans, then put it back in, or you could maintain a list of known groups then add a like operator to your join, but you may still end up with some rows in many groups depending on the groups.

Anyway, have fun, hope this helps, interesting problem.

Comment: levenstein is awesome

Answer (score 0):

For example if your group contain `group_name` you can do something like this

```
SELECT *
FROM `table`
WHERE `column` LIKE '%{$group_name}%'
```

This will give you all results which contain that specific group name. You can do `UPDATE` as well with this clause.

```
UPDATE groups
SET group_id=1771
WHERE `column` LIKE '%{$group_name}%'
```

Comment: `Red Hot (Live in CA)` is not like `Red Hot Chili Peppers`. Also don't advise in using `mysql_*`.

Comment: I removed mysql_*, i prefer PDO as well. @chris85

Comment: @chris85 There is *nothing `LIKE` the Red Hot Chili Peppers!* ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- ahahahahahahahahah +1

Comment: @AleksandarĐokić *hehe* ;-) *Give it away now* ;-) gawd I love that line.